# How to create a ranking in r for rownames on the basis of aggregation of data by taking the average of mean and hp in mtcars dataset?

Tags: r, ranking

I want the average of numeric columns `mpg` and `hp`. In this data frame the rank of each manufacturer has to be separetely calculated for each manufacturer on the basis of `mpg` and `hp`.The final metric value of manufacturers would be `0.6 * mpg + 0.4 * hp`. Please see the code below:

```
data(mtcars)
t<-mtcars
d<-aggregate(mpg~hp,data = t,FUN = mean)
d
```

By doing this we get a list. But this list does not contain the name of manufacturers.  How we can get a rank of the manufacturers? .

Comment: # From the above code we get a list of mean of mpg on the basis of hp. But my task is to Aggregate the data ,for each manufactured  by taking the average of numeric columns (mpg and hp).The rank of each manufacturer has to be separetely calculated for each manufacturer on the basis of mpg and hp.The final metric value of manufacturers would be (0.6*mpg+0.4*hp)???

Comment: Put all important information in the question. Don't add comments.

Comment: *"by doing this we get a list. But this list do not contain the name of manufacturers."* `aggregate` returns a `data.frame` (not a `list`). What do you mean by "manufacturers"? Do you mean the car names, i.e. the row names? You are averaging `mpg` per `hp`; multiple rows are summarised to return a mean `mpg`. In general, you can't return a single car name for the aggregated `data.frame` (unless there is only one value). Your question is not clear.

Comment: Hi...You are right aggregate function returns a data.frame.I want the average of numeric columns mpg and hp.In this data frame the rank of each manufacturer has to be separetely calculated for each manufacturer on the basis of mpg and hp.The final metric value of manufacturers would be (0.6*mpg+0.4*hp)???

Answer (score 0):

Please see below, supposedly that the first word of row name will give a name of manufacturer:

```
data(mtcars)

t <- mtcars
t$mfg <- vapply(rownames(mtcars), function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " "))[1], "")
d <- aggregate(. ~ mfg, data = t, FUN = function(x) mean(x))[, c("mfg", "mpg", "hp")]
d[, 2:3] <- lapply(d[, 2:3], rank) 
d$final <- rank(0.6 * d$mpg + 0.4 *d$hp)
head(d)
```

Output, the final metric is in a `final` column:

```
       mfg  mpg   hp final
1      AMC  7.0 12.5   4.0
2 Cadillac  1.5 16.0   1.0
3   Camaro  3.0 19.5   5.0
4 Chrysler  5.0 18.0   7.0
5   Datsun 17.0  5.0  10.5
6    Dodge  8.0 12.5   6.0
```